# Firebase unable to export to JSON

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, export

I am tring to export Firebase to JSON using the console. I managed to export some of the nodes, however, for some nodes, I am getting this error message:

File not found

```
Firefox can't find the file at https://srs-db.firebaseio.com/table2.json?print=pretty&format=export&download=db-tables2-export.json&auth=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTYxNTQ4NTAsImV4cCI6MTUxNjE1ODQ1MCwidiI6MCwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.M_CMQoTLBDDaR8Ri09M7X8qrBjai6BZQUJayaBjHIT4.

    Check the file name for capitalisation or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, When I click on `Export to JSON` firebase gives me same error but when I copy url and open incognito mode and past url, Download of json file is started.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by Chirag worked for me too. When I click on Export to JSON firebase gives me same error but when I copy url and open incognito mode and past url, Download of json file started.